# Javascript + svg, draw sinus (wave) line between two given points

Tags: javascript, svg, trigonometry

I am trying to write a javascript loader with svg. Idea is that it is circle that is being filled from bottom to top equally on both sides and the top line of loader is a sinus wave continuesly moving from left to right.

I was able to create an arc for loader based on percentage like this:

```
    var d_arc = function(x, y, r, sa, ea) { // calculate arc path from given parameters
        var start = pfa(x, y, r, ea),
            end = pfa(x, y, r, sa),
            sw = ea - sa <= 180 ? '0' : '1';

        return '<path d="M ' + start.x + ' ' + start.y + ' A ' + r + ' ' + r + ' 0 ' + sw + ' 0 ' + end.x + ' ' + end.y + '" class="path-progress"></path>';
    };
```

Above code is essentially creating "U" shaped arc that is becoming full circle if You pass 100% load as parameter. The problem now is with top line that needs to be a animated wave. I tried to do it with quadratic bezier curve but i had problems calculating the points inside. I only know start(x,y) and end(x,y) points, dont know how to calculate other ones.

Second approach was this script:

https://jsfiddle.net/assa0r70/7/

but its not working for me because i cannot specify start and end points and sine line is always drawed in wrong place.

The final goal is to fill entire shape ("U" arc and closing sine line) with some color, so the sine line must conitnue the arc path from above code

`d="M ' + start.x + ' ' + start.y + ' A ' + r + ' ' + r + ' 0 ' + sw + ' 0 ' + end.x + ' ' + end.y + ' //sine line continue here`.

This is a full code of approach (not working, just idea):

https://jsfiddle.net/9hnuzp1d/11/

does anyone have an idea how to create that sine line from point A to point B, that can be animated like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/assa0r70/7/ ? ;)

Comment: It seems to me the example you link to does almost everything you need. Why not just modify it so that it has a configurable startX and endX? See: https://jsfiddle.net/assa0r70/8/

Comment: unfortunetely this is the outcome https://jsfiddle.net/9hnuzp1d/13/ do You think it can be fixed?

Comment: It only seem to work if you set 50 %, in any other case it will be broken, thats why i was thinking at first to use bezier curve, as it would stick perfectly to the start and end point and start waving from that

Comment: You should use a fixed width wave and mask it with a circle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w2aju18b/

Comment: yeah that would make sense, can You try to apply this method to my case? iam trying but it doesnt go well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example animates a polyline, built via a parametric equation for a sine wave. Also it uses Paul Lebeau's suggestion of mask circle. It will move up/down the circle based on percentage selection.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Animate Sine Wave</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body onload=animateSineWave() style='font-family:arial'>
<center>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
Animate a sine wave, using parametric equation to build a polyline. Move it up/down circle via Percentage selection.
</div>

<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
    <defs>
        <mask id="circle">
            <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="200" fill="white"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
     <polyline id=sineWave stroke=blue stroke-width=3  fill="#ccc" stroke="red" mask="url(#circle)" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="200" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
</div>
Percentage:<select id=percentSelect>
<option value=.1 >10%</option>
<option value=.3 >30%</option>
<option value=.5 >50%</option>
<option selected value=.8 >80%</option>
</select>

</center>

<script>
function buildSineWave(amplitude)
{
    //---mask fill bottom of circle
    var startPoint=[0,400]
    var endPoint=[400,400]

    var originX=0
    var percent=parseFloat(percentSelect.options[percentSelect.selectedIndex].value)
    var originY=400*(1-percent)

    var width=400
    var pointSpacing=1
    var angularFrequency=.02
    var phaseAngle=90

    var origin = { //origin of axes
    x: originX,
    y: originY
    }

    var points=[]
    points.push(startPoint)
    var x,y
    for (var i = 0; i < width/pointSpacing; i++)
    {
        x= i * pointSpacing + origin.x
        y= Math.sin(angularFrequency*(i + phaseAngle)) * amplitude + origin.y
        points.push([x,y])
    }
    points.push(endPoint)
    sineWave.setAttribute("points",points.join(" "))
}

function animateSineWave()
{
    var range=60 //--amplitude +/- ---
    var FPS=120  //---frames per second---
    var duration=2000 //---ms, 2 seconds---
    //----core animation function---
  new AnimateJS(
  {
   delay: 1000/FPS,
   duration: duration,
   delta: linear,
   output: function(delta)
   {
                if(delta<=.5)
                var amplitude=range*delta
                else
                var amplitude=60-range*delta

                buildSineWave(amplitude)
                if(progress==1)//---run again---
                    animateSineWave()
   }
  })

}
/*---generalized animate core function
 Inspired by: Ilya Kantor - http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation
*/
var linear=function linear(p){return p}//---linear---
//----Animate Object---
var AnimateJS=function(options){
    this.options=options
 var start = new Date
 var iT = setInterval(
 function(){
  var timePassed = new Date - start
  var progress = timePassed / options.duration
  if (progress > 1) progress = 1
  this.progress=progress
  var delta = options.delta(progress)
  options.output(delta)
  if (progress == 1)clearInterval(iT);
 },options.delay)
}


</script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```